# Map a column of cells to hyperlink of flies = to cell value in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column of MD5 hashes (string value) and I'd like to make each be a hyperlink to the file with the same name as the cell value. The files are in the same folder as the spreadsheet.

The Excel column looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of Excel data]

Filenames are the same. Here's a sample from another part of the list:

[image: Screen shot of directory listing]

I need each Excel cell's data to be a hyperlink to its file so that the file will open (in its associated application) with a click on the link.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you looking for a formula, VBA code, or a guide?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Copy the cell content    *(hit F2, select text, hold CTRL hit C, let go, hit ESC)*
hold CTRL hit K, to "edit hyperlink",
type `file://./`    *(Windows should accept the last `/`, but may be you need `\` instead)*
and then immediately following that; hold CTRL and hit V to paste the filename,
hit ENTER to finish the job.

The cell should now be a hyperlink to the file in the current dir (assumed to be same where the excel file was loaded from).

*The above from memory, untested, result in the link part of the hyperlink should be `file://./filename.ext` or `file://.\filename.ext`*